# Error after installing MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, osx-elcapitan

I have NodeJS installed on my mac.

```
$ node -v
v4.2.1
```

I'm trying to install bower. Here is the result:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Kevin/Sites/npm-debug.log
```

I tried to do:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/_locks: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/bower/1.6.3/package/package.json: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/bower/1.6.3/package: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/bower/1.6.3/package.tgz: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/bower/1.6.3: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/bower: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/Kevin/.npm/n: Operation not permitted
```

It seems like I don't have permission at all.
I can not install anything.

How can I fix that?

Comment: in which way you did the installation?

Comment: I installed it with the downloaded .pkg, not with homebrew. And after for bower "npm install -g bower"

Comment: And "sudo npm install -g bower" works?

Comment: No "sudo npm install -g bower" does not work

Comment: I installed from .pkg too and executed  "sudo npm install -g bower" and works fine, i'm on OSX El Capitan too.

Maybe there's some adicional steps that you made before that are no considered here?

Anyway, for development environments i use   nvm  from https://github.com/creationix/nvm ,  which allow to change between any Node.js version really quick.

Use the git clone way to install.

Comment: I think it's a problem about my privilege. Because I just figured each time I'm trying to do a "chmod" command I have this message: "chmod: Unable to change file mode on 'the folder': Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to reinstall mac OS X El Capitan.
After that it worked.

I'm now using docker to do not have this kind of problem again.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the following commands in a terminal to fix this permission error.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then you will no longer need to use sudo with any npm installs.